# Why does VI not run when called from cron?

Tags: cron, vi

I can run this command perfectly at the command line and it works as expected.

```
 /usr/bin/vi /tmp/test.txt -c ":%s/test/production/g" -c ":wq"
```

However the same command run from a cron job does not work at all.

```
hostname:/etc/cron.d $ cat LOCAL-criggie-testing
* * * * * root   /usr/bin/vi /tmp/test.txt -c ":%s/test/production/g" -c ":wq"
```

Why does vi not run from cron ?  How to make it work?

<sup>Yes I'm aware there's dozens of better ways to do this but its a simplified example</sup>

Answer (score 0):

**`VI` requires a terminal to work.**

Being a VIsual editor, it assumes that a human is running it at a console or some interactive remote session.  When called from cron, the console is missing, so process fails to work as expected.

Doubtless there are other commands which make similar assumptions.

**Option 1**. Run the same command but wrap it inside `screen` in detached mode.  When the command exits, screen will also exit.

```
screen -d -m   /usr/bin/vi /tmp/test.txt -c ":%s/test/production/g" -c ":wq"
```

**Option 2**. Rewrite the command to not use `vi`  This may not be possible. 
This uses `sed`/Stream EDitor with "in-place" option to avoid needing a temporary file

```
sed -i /tmp/test.txt -e "s/test/production/g"
```

---

<sup>Full Disclosure: The original problem I had was more complex, but with the same root cause. We had a script file that uses `ldapvi` to generate some output, and being a derivative of `vi` had the same reluctance to run without a console.
Additionally, the script was part of `Check_mk` running a shell script via a telnet connection.  So there were a number of other possibilities to confuse the issue.  Resolved by swapping out `ldapvi` for `ldapsearch` with different parameters.

Documenting this because I couldn't find the answer anywhere, even knowing what the cause was.</sup>